# TypError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, tuple found

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples

I have a column with tuples which I would like to remove the brackets from.

Example

| words |
| --- |
| (hello,me) |
| (what,can) |
| (ring, dog) |

I have tried this:

```
df['words'].agg(','.join)
```

Unfortunately I receive the error in the title.

I would like this output:

| words |
| --- |
| hello,me |
| what,can |
| ring, dog |

Any solution?

Also, strangely enough, with a different dataset that line of code works. Any ideas why?

Comment: which pandas version? this works fine with the latest version

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [df.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) to update the `words` column with the new value by applying a function to modify the value of each row

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'words': [('hello','me'), ('what','can')]})
df['words'] = df.apply (lambda row: ','.join(row[0]), axis=1)
```

Edit: come to think of it, your original approach using `df['words'].agg` should also work but you need to assign it the `words` column for it to make change to the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'words': [('hello','me'), ('what','can')]})
df['words'] = df['words'].agg(','.join)
print(df)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

I also get this error
```
TypeError: <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
```
Any idea?

Comment: I have done it. 

I still get that output

Comment: @OnikRahman could you specify which python and pandas version you're using? This seems strange as `axis` is a known argument for `df.apply`